# Java Algorithm for Project Euler Q20

Tags: java, algorithm

n! means n  X  (n  -  1)  X  ...  X  3  X  2  X  1

For example, 10! = 10  X  9  X  ...  X  3  X  2  X  1 = 3628800,
   and the sum of the digits in the number 10! is 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 =
   27.

## Find the sum of the digits in the number 100!

```
import java.util.*;
class ProjectEuler_20{
    public static double factorial(double number){
        double num=1;
        for(int i=2;i<=number;i++){
            num=num*i;
            }
        return num;
        }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double number=factorial(100);
        long num=(long)number;
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;num>0;i++){
            sum=sum+num%10;
            num=num/10;
            }
        System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Why do I always get the sum of the digits of Long.MAX_VALUE? Is there a way to approach for the real answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project-Euler -- Problem20](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206158/project-euler-problem20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` cannot accurately hold a number as large as `100!`; it can only hold an *approximation*.

You must use `BigInteger` to *accurately* perform the calculation.

Here's a 1 line answer:

```java
int sum = IntStream.range(1, 101)       // stream ints from 1 up to 100
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)      // ready for BigInteger constructor
        .map(BigInteger::new)           // create a BigInteger from the String
        .reduce(BigInteger::multiply)   // multiply them all together
        .get().toString().chars()       // stream the digits of the result
        .map(i -> i - '0')              // convert char as int to its digit value
        .sum();                         // sum the digits
```

Result:

```
648
```

---

fyi, `100!` is `93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000`